# How to get the MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException message in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Im trying to handle exception

this is the stacktrace;

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) 
    ...
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'testemail@gmail.com' for key 'UK_n7ihswpy07ci568w34q0oi8he'
```

when I try to get the messsase using the getMessage() method, the message get was the "could not execute statement" from ConstraintViolationException,

but what I want is to get the 
"Duplicate entry 'testemail@gmail.com' for key 'UK_n7ihswpy07ci568w34q0oi8he'" message from MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.

here is my catching process

```
catch(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    message = "MySQLIntegrity,\n Duplicate Entry, \n" + e.getMessage();
}
catch(ConstraintViolationException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    message = "ConstraintViolation,\n Duplicate Entry, \n" + e.getMessage();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    message = "Exception rule,\n" + e.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
catch(ConstraintViolationException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    message = "ConstraintViolation,\n Duplicate Entry, \n" + e.getCause().getMessage();
}
```

**Caused by:** *com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'testemail@gmail.com' for key 'UK_n7ihswpy07ci568w34q0oi8he'*

it's original exception

---

simple variant :

```
private String getRootCauseMessage(Throwable ex){
    if(ex.getCause() == null){
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
    return getRootCauseMessage(ex.getCause());
}
```

or

```
Throwable cause = originalException;
while(cause.getCause() != null) {
    cause = cause.getCause();
}
```

But as it simple variants they might go to infinity recursio.you can add some counter and count recursive calls. If it more 100 return empty string

if you have access to apache commons use it. 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html , there is getRootCause method that give you root exception and you can get masseage from one/

Comment: yes it gives what I need. thank you. followup question: so if I used the getCause() method, then I can get what is caused of the exception, but what if there are many exception, will the getCause() will give me all the exceptions? thanks a lot sir. you saved me.

Comment: thank you sir sbjavateam for your very informative answer, it helps me a lot.